# Can I see the file created in Android Tablet by file.createNewFile()?

Tags: android, file, creation

I created a file by file.createNewFile() command in "data/data/com.android.bonvoyage" folder to test file creation in the internal storage of my android tablet.

I found that the file should be visible when I have root account, but I want to find a way
to see the file created without root permission.
I don't care where the file is created, just want to see and test it on actual tablet.

Can I do that?

The process was successful by

```
    File file = new File("data/data/com.android.bonvoyage/myfile.txt");
    boolean tf = false;
    if (!file.exists()) {
        try {
            tf = file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            Toast.makeText(this, ioe.toString(), 5000).show();
            //ioe.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            Toast.makeText(this, "File Created? " + Boolean.toString(tf), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: shouldn't it be "/data ... " ?

Comment: also, don't log exceptions in toast. log them in logs.

Answer (score 0):

With root explorer or any file explorer that supports root you could browse to: data/data/com.android.bonvoyage/myfile.txt and look whether its there or not?

Answer (score 0):

Write the file to the sdcard and then you can see it with the file browser without root permissions.

Use the following code (taking from the android guide) to open a file in the pictures folder for example:

```
public File getAlbumStorageDir(String albumName) {
    // Get the directory for the user's public pictures directory. 
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), albumName);
    if (!file.mkdirs()) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Directory not created");
    }
    return file;
}
```

The full guide can be found here:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html#WriteExternalStorage